# Janusgraph Is Not Working Due To Serialization Problem

Tags: groovy, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

Why are serialization errors still occurring? 
I've been trying to get JanusGraph working with much difficulties. 
I've configured JanusGraph server using the following:

```yaml
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8182
    evaluationTimeout: 30000
    channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
    graphs:
      graph: /etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph.properties
      ConfigurationManagementGraph: /opt/janusgraph/conf/janusgraph-cql-configurationgraph.properties
    scriptEngines:
      gremlin-groovy:
        plugins:
          org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin: {}
          org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {}
          org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.jsr223.TinkerGraphGremlinPlugin: {}
          org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin:
            classImports:
              - java.lang.Math
            methodImports:
              - java.lang.Math#*
          org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin:
            files:
              - scripts/empty-sample.groovy
    serializers:
      - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1
        config:
          ioRegistries:
            - org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry
      - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1
        config:
          serializeResultToString: true
      - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
        config:
          ioRegistries:
            - org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry
      - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
        config:
          serializeResultToString: true
      - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
        config:
          ioRegistries:
            - org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry
    processors:
      - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor
        config:
          sessionTimeout: 28800000
      - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor
        config:
          cacheExpirationTime: 600000
          cacheMaxSize: 1000
    metrics:
      consoleReporter:
        enabled: false
        interval: 180000
      csvReporter:
        enabled: true
        interval: 180000
        fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
      jmxReporter:
        enabled: true
      slf4jReporter:
        enabled: true
        interval: 180000
      graphiteReporter:
        enabled: false
        interval: 180000
    maxInitialLineLength: 4096
    maxHeaderSize: 8192
    maxChunkSize: 8192
    maxContentLength: 65536
    maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
    resultIterationBatchSize: 64
    writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
    writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
    threadPoolWorker: 1
    gremlinPool: 8
    graphManager: org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager
```

I noticed that sending the same command to the server results in different responses. 
Depending on the serializer on the client side, results range from success to serialization errors. 
Since the server's to use all available serializers,
why are serialization errors still occurring?

On the client end, I created a cluster:

```js
    var registry = TypeSerializerRegistry.build().addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.instance()).create();
    var cluster = Cluster.build("localhost").port(8182).serializer(new GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1(registry)).create();
```

The traversal object using the following:

```js
    g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "my_traversal"));
```

Next a vertex is added with

```js
    var json = mapper.valueToTree(obj);
    g.addV("LABEL").property("property", json).next();
```

I'm using the `ObjectMapper` from JanusGraph

```js
import org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

But I'm still getting the following serialization errors:

```bash
    io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: An error occurred during serialization of this request (REQUEST REMOVED) - it could not be sent to the server - Reason: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: java.io.IOException: Serializer for type org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode not found
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:104) ~[netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717) ~[netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764) ~[netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1071) ~[netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) ~[netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Why is the serializer for `ObjectNode` not available when [JanusGraph Docs](https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/serializer/) states that it should? 
I'm really stuck and couldn't find any good information on the web.

Could someone please help?
Thank you.